# C++ How to tell apart specific object types from a Heterogeneous Collection?

Tags: c++, object, collections, polymorphism, heterogeneous

So if i have a heterogeneous collection of Car objects

Car* c = {truck, van, convertible}

If the collection of objects was random and I wanted to go through the collection with a for loop, how can I test for the specific object type?

Comment: Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: Just redesign your app so you don't need to know real type.

Comment: Why do you need the object type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use a `dynamic_cast`:

```
if (truck* truck_p = dynamic_cast<truck*>(car_p)) {
  // car_p points at a truck
}
```

`dynamic_cast` will check the dynamic type of the object being pointed to by `car_p` and only allow the cast if it is a `truck`. If it is not a `truck`, it will give the null pointer value and therefore the `if` condition will fail.

However, the need to test a dynamic type like this suggests bad code design. The whole point of polymorphism is that you can treat any of the derived objects as though it were a base object - there should be no need to test exactly which derived type it was. If you need to check the dynamic type of a `Car` so that you can do some `truck`-specific operation on it, then you shouldn't be throwing that `truck` into a container of `Car*`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to know the derived type then polymorphism isn't the right tool for the job. I would suggest using a [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html) or equivalent to implement a [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at RTTI:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information

It's Run Time Type Information. You could also add a member variable into each derived type stating what type it is, and use that to check.